# Difference between 2 ember-date time objects in days

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to tell the difference between 2 ember-date time objects in days?

For example, if I have the following 2 date objects

```
var start_date = Ember.DateTime.parse(app.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d');
var end_date = Ember.DateTime.parse(app.end_date, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

I can tell which one is greater than the other like this:

```
Ember.DateTime.compareDate(end_date, start_date);
```

But is there a way of getting the difference in days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure there is an API to get difference in days (something like in `JodaTime`).
I know that `Ember.DateTime` basically extends the regular js `Date` so you can do something like:

```
var date1 = Ember.DateTime.create({ hour: 5, timezone: 300 });
var date2 = Ember.DateTime.create({ hour: 10, timezone: 0 });
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays)​;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: There is no getTime of the ember-datetime object.  It needs to be accessed via date1.get('_ms').  This is by convention a private variable but does allow me to progress.  Thanks!